# Report name was not specified --Crystal report RAS 9

Tags: crystal-reports

The crystal reports throws an error " A report name was not specified".

I am using

1. RAS 9
2. ParameterField.asp
3. ActivexViewer.asp
4. rptserver.asp( Its not grabbing the reportname in this file)

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to understand an error without knowing the code. A little code can be more helpful to answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<Report>` tag in `<CrystalReportViewer>` like this:

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
<CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
<Report FileName="CrystalReport.rpt">
</Report>
</CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

**OR**

Add Crystal Reports source dynamically like this:

```
ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("Username","Password","Server","Database");
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
```